# What does #arr[*] mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I came across a script with some code like this:

```
arr=($p)
np=${#arr[*]}
```

p is a string of integer pairs: "0,1 2,4 3,5" etc. First of all, I'm not 100% sure what the () do in the first line, but I think it just turns the things into an associative array of sorts? That may not be correct either .... But more than that, I'm at a complete loss as to what the second line does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parentheses in the first turn the result into an array, and it will be assigned indexes starting from 0 and split according to `IFS` (which by default includes whitespace). The `${#arr[*]}}` gives the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Ah, thanks! so each element of the array would be "0,1" and "2,4". That makes sense.